# Ionic with SwiperJS for slides is jerky on Android. Fine on iOS and web

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, swiper.js

I just implemented swiperjs in my Ionic + Capacitor app and it works great on web and iOS.  I have pretty crappy performance on my physical Android device though, really jerky animation from slide to slide.

I created a dummy app using the pure html of each slide and it works well.
See videos below.

I am assuming it is something to do with using *ngIf or variables in the slide template.
I have turned the device offline to make sure it is not doing anything unexpected and there is no change
Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Angular slides - Jerky
https://youtu.be/UYdxmpSUysk

HTML only slides - Smooth
https://youtu.be/d0cUVCydTa0

EDIT:
I have copied the same code below into my demo html only app and it does make it a bit more jerky but nowhere near as much as the main app.
So the ngIfs and ngClass/ngStyles do affect the animation but it must also be something else or just a combination of things.

Not sure if it is related to these issues:
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3899
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1123304
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4187
My device has webView Chrome v92.0.4515.131

UPDATE:
I have tried adding the following to my androidManifest.xml with no luck
android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Code:

```
<div class="permit-container" (click)="dismissModal()">
    <div #cardContainer class="permit" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" 
      [ngClass]="{'permit-bkg-image': permitShowVirtualCardBgImage}"
      [ngStyle]="{
        'background': permitShowVirtualCardBgImage ? (tenant.style.permitBgColor ? tenant.style.permitBgColor + ', ' + permitBackgroundImage : permitBackgroundImage) : (tenant.style.permitBgColor ? tenant.style.permitBgColor : 'var(--ion-color-permit-card-bk-gradient)')
      }" 
      >
      <div *ngIf="isNetworkConnected" class="status-header branded-font-heading-large">
        {{member.isActive === true ? tenant.text.textUserTerm + ' #' + member.code : tenant.text.textInactiveAccount ? tenant.text.textInactiveAccount : 'Unpaid'}} 
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!isNetworkConnected" class="status-header branded-font-heading-large">
        Offline - No Connection
      </div>
  
      <ion-list *ngIf="member?.isActive" lines="none" [ngClass]="{'ion-list-item-family': member.membershipPackageName === 'Family Membership'}">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap tenant-name branded-font-heading" [ngClass]="{'tenant-name-long': tenant.name.length > 20 }">
            {{tenant.name}}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
            <h3>{{member.firstName}} {{member.lastName}}</h3>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="member.membershipPackage && (member.membershipPackageName !== 'Family Membership' || (member.membershipPackageName === 'Family Membership' && member.familyCode))">
          <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
            <h3>Type: {{member.membershipPackage.name}}</h3>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="member.membershipPackageName === 'Family Membership' && member.familyCode">
          <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
            <div class="family-code-container">
              <h3>
                Family Code: <div class="family-code">{{member.familyCode}}</div>
              </h3>
              <fa-icon class="icon-copy" [icon]="faCopy" size="2x" (click)="onCopyFamilyCode()"></fa-icon>
            </div>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="!member.isSubscriptionMembership">
          <ion-label>
            <h3>
              Expiry: {{member.expiryDate ? (member.expiryDate | date: 'd MMM yy') : ''}}
            </h3>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="member.isSubscriptionMembership">
          <ion-label>
            <h3>
              Renewal
              {{membershipAppSubscription.dateNextPayment ? (membershipAppSubscription.dateNextPayment | date: 'd MMM yyyy') : ''}}
            </h3>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  
      <div *ngIf="member && !member.isActive" class="unpaid-blurb">
        {{tenant.text.textWhyRegister}}
      </div>
  
      <div *ngIf="!partner" class="logo-container" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': tenant?.style?.permitLogoBgColor ? tenant?.style?.permitLogoBgColor : 'transparent'}">
        <ion-img *ngIf="!tenant.isBrandedTenant" [src]=tenant.imageUrlLogo></ion-img>
        <ion-img *ngIf="tenant.isBrandedTenant" [src]=tenant.imageUrlLogoLocalTemp></ion-img>
      </div>
  
      <app-deal-card *ngIf="partner" [partner]="partner" [isStandalone]="true" [isClickable]="false" [showPermitIcon]="false"></app-deal-card>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: try to set mode="ios".

Comment: @RaviAshara that is only for Ionic components.  This is the https://swiperjs.com/ plugin which is now recommended to use as ion-slides is being deprecated.